# How to show only fontawesome 4 icons in iconpicker?

Tags: jquery, icons, font-awesome

I'm using iconpicker from here:

https://github.com/farbelous/fontawesome-iconpicker

I want to show only 'fa' icons, not 'fab', 'far', 'fas', etc.

I already tried it, but it didn't worked for me:

```
icons: [], // list of icon objects [{title:String, searchTerms:String}]. By default, all Font Awesome icons are included.
fullClassFormatter: function(val) {
    return 'fa ' + val;
},
```

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `fa`and `fas`???

Comment: I'm not aware sir, is there some problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other peoples who want to the same thing, just use iconpicker v 1.4.0, which can be found here:

https://github.com/farbelous/fontawesome-iconpicker/releases

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your question makes not much sense. The prefix `fa` to select an icon (eg `<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>` was used with [FontAwesome4](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/). With version 5 which has several styles/categories/families of fonts, this inital specificer now has to be one of:

- `fab` - FontAwesome brands
- `fas` - FontAwesome solid
- `far` - FontAwesome regular
- `fal`-  FontAwesome light
  (But note that Free version does not have as much icons as Pro, most frequently only those of `fas`).

Previous example would now read `<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>`. (´pencil`only in Pro).

So a new question might be how one could restrict the choices within iconpicker to certain subsets. Or did your question arise because you want to use iconpicker on a FA4-Site? Mixing FA4 and 5 will not be possibly, I'm afraid.

Comment: the problem is my system works with FA4 and for now we can't update to FA5, that's why I just want our users to choose only FA4 icons

Comment: The question you should really ask then is "How to make Iconpicker work with FA4"? Unfortunately I did not find much useful info on that site, so I'm afraif I can't help.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did it by using iconpicker ver 1.4.0